# NMinimize with a matrix argument

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization, arguments

How does one specify that an argument in `NMinimize` should be understood as a matrix (of a given dimension)? For example, say I have two square matrices $F\succeq0$ and $G$ of same dimension, I would like to solve the following dummy program, $$\min_{0\preceq X\preceq F} ~\mathrm{Tr}(GX).$$

I have tried the following,

```
F = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
G = {{1, 1}, {1, 1}};
constraints = {PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ[F - X], 
   PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ[X]};
objective = Tr[G.X];
NMinimize[Join[{objective}, constraints], X]
```

only to see it try to look for `X` scalar. I would like to let `NMinimize` know that it should look for square matrices of the right dimension, how could I do that?

Comment: A question that has to do with the context: is this related to semidefinite programming or am I misreading your OP?


  : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming

Comment: Well, this dummy problem is, but I am actually looking at non-convex programs.